# Interfaces and Indexers

Tags: c#, .net, interface, indexer

I have an interface which is being used like this:

```
var descr = new IMyInterface[3];
```

At first glance I thought that this doesn't make any sense since it looks like an Interface is being instantiated (which isn't possible). So I think that this is probably a call to an Indexer defined in the interface but I still don't quite understand how this works. So my question is:

1. What is this call doing? Is it calling an indexer defined in the interface?
2. What implementation of the interface's indexer is being used?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: maybe you should also explain your goal, in order to help you to correct the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an array of 3 `IMyInterface`... but each item is null in the array.

Comment: Haha yup we just figured it out as well. Pretty embarassing. We read into it way too much thinking about indexers and what not. Thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 2):

It's creating an array of `IMyInterface` with three elements. i.e. a `IMyInterface[]`. This is just the usual `new T[n]` syntax for array creation, no different from `new int[3]`.

Conceptually it's the something similar to `new Array<IMyInterface>(3)`, except that array is no generic type for historical reasons.

An array is a concrete class, so you can create an instance of it, even if the member type is an interface. The members will be initialized to `default(T)` which is `null` for interfaces.

This is unrelated to indexers.

---

It is possible to define indexers on interfaces just like you can do it on classes. But the syntax for using them does not involve `new`.

It's also possible to instantiate interfaces in certain COM related scenarios.

Comment: Thank you for the help. We just figured it out ourselves. It's incredibly obvious if you think about it for a minute. We were reading into it way too much haha. Thanks :)